# How to solve the ThresholdRule TypeError while using google-cloud-billing-budgets library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I'm using `google-cloud-billing-budgets` to automatically create budgets, but I'm getting errors when I try to create the *ThresholdRule*.
My code looks like this.

```
    new_thresholde_rule = budgets.ThresholdRule({
        'threshold_percent' : [0.9]
    })

    new_budget_details = budgets.Budget({
        'display_name': projectId,
        'amount': new_amount,
        'threshold_rules': new_thresholde_rule,
    })

    new_budget = client.create_budget(
        request = {
            'parent': BILLING_ACCOUNT,
            'budget': new_budget_details,
        }
    )
```

The error is this:

```
TypeError: [0.9] has type list, but expected one of: int, long, float
```

I have been following the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/billingbudgets/latest/budgets_v1/types.html#google.cloud.billing.budgets_v1.types.ThresholdRule), but it did not give me any hint.

Comment: Try using this **'threshold_percent' : 0.9** instead of **'threshold_percent' : [0.9]** (As we are passing the value in square braces it might consider the value as list).

Comment: I did that but I got this error ```TypeError: Value must be iterable```

Comment: Try using  **'threshold_percent' : 0.9,** or Try using this **'threshold_percent' : (0.9, )**

Comment: The solution wasn't there, I have to use brackets in `new_thresholde_rule` So I will have this `[new_thresholde_rule]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can solve it. This is the solution:

```
    new_budget_details = budgets.Budget({
        'display_name': projectId,
        'amount': new_amount,
        'threshold_rules': [new_thresholde_rule],
    })
```

I have to use brackets in `'threshold_rules': [new_thresholde_rule]`, that's all. It's working.

Comment: Since your issue is resolved can you please accept the solution you have posted?